# Phonegap detecting tablet or smartphone using the same resolution

Tags: android, css, cordova, responsive-design

I'm using Phonegap for a mobile application. 
Now i want to detect is there a smartphone or an tablet?

I think something like:

```
var isMobile = navigator.userAgent.match(/(iPhone|iPod|iPad|Android|BlackBerry)/);
```

will not work if i have an android smartphone or tablet.

The @Media library is also not what I'm looking for because a tablet and a smartphone can have the same resolution (so width px cant decide between tablet and smartphone).

Is there an another way to detect it?
I would be realy grateful for your help.

Comment: use device width and height. tablet width is from 600px(~590px).

Answer (score 1):

You have a cordova plugin to determine if the device is a tablet or not on Android and iOS. You can find this plugin here : [istablet](http://plugins.cordova.io/#/package/uk.co.workingedge.phonegap.plugin.istablet)

Comment: Thank you! Can i also decide to take different css-files depending on True/False or would you suggest an other approach? What i mean: window.isTablet== True, take tablet.css else: take smartphone.css. Is this possible?

Comment: Yes you can add a css width jquery $(document.createElement("link")).attr({rel:"stylesheet", type:"text/css", href:"styles.css"}) but the mediaQueries can be a solution to reduce the loading time and avoid javascript.

Answer (score -1):

The best way  will be to create a js file and and write your conditions to check the device in the js and then to load the stylesheet dynamically something like this

In your html (index.html)

```
<head>
   //headers.............
   <script type="text/javascript" src="js/styles.js"></script>
  //headers..............
</head>
```

In styles.js

```
if ((navigator.platform=="iPhone"))
    { 
        document.write('<link href="css/iphone.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />');
    }
    else
    { 
        document.write('<link href="css/ipad.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />');
    }
```

Something like this where iphone.css and ipad.css are your different style sheets accordingly